# Change multiple ATTR with same CONTENT

Tags: imacros

I want to replace the content of multiple input fields with the same content, something like:

```
ATTR=ID1, ID2, ID3 CONTENT=newContent
```

Comment: See the [iMacros Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imacros/info) for Recommendations on how to ask a (good) Question in this Tag... :idea:

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that there's no way to do it. I had to copy and paste the same line multiple times just changing the ATT on each of them.

Comment: Hey Matheus,
Welcome to stack overflow community. Suggestion - Please add such a comments under your question as a comment instead of Answer. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).